# Customized protocol's method is not calling in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, protocols

I am having RouteSelectController from which I am navigating to RouteInfoController.

```
-(void)GoToRouteInfo
{
    RouteInfoController *controller = [[RouteInfoController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RouteInfoController" bundle:nil];

controller.delegate = self;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller release];
}
```

In RouteInfoController.h I am creating my customized protocol like

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol RouteInfoDelegate;
@interface RouteInfoController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, WptInfoDelegate>
{

    id<RouteInfoDelegate> delegate;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate
@end

@protocol RouteInfoDelegate

- (void) deleteWptFromRouteAndAppWithUID;

@end
```

In RouteInfoController.m I called this delegate method like:

```
#import "MapViewController.h"
@class MapViewController;
@implementation RouteInfoController
@synthesize delegate;

-(void)callRouteDelegateMethod
{
  [self.delegate deleteWptFromRouteAndAppWithUID];
}
```

And the definition of this method is in MapViewController.m like:

```
#import "RouteInfoController.h"
@interface MapViewController () <UIScrollViewDelegate,RouteInfoDelegate>
{
    //.....................................
}

-(void) deleteWptFromRouteAndAppWithUID // The problem here is this delegate method is not called
{
    NSLog(@"\n Inside delete Way point...");

}
```

Edit: And when the control reaches to that delegate method in

> -(void)callRouteDelegateMethod

in RouteInfoController I am get a crash message in my console like :

> [RouteSelectController deleteWptFromRouteAndAppWithUID]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x6eb4eb0

Edit2:

In RootInfoController I am having a method on didselect of any cell of table view it calls this method

```
- (void) viewWptInfoControllerAtIndex: (int)index{

    WptInfoViewController *controller = [[WptInfoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WptInfoViewController" bundle:nil];
    controller.asRootController = NO;
    controller.delegate = self;
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [route.routeWaypoints objectAtIndex:index];
    NPLibWaypoint *libWpt = [NPLibWaypoint initWithDictionary:dict AndDelegateDS:delegateDS];
    controller.libWpt = libWpt;
       [libWpt release];
    controller.isFromRouteInfo = YES;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    [controller release];

}
```

Guy's cpls anyone suggest me How to resolve this and what's wrong I done.

Anyone's Help is deeply Appreciated.

Thanks All,
Monish.

Comment: where does "RouteSelectController" come from? i thought you wanted to use MapViewController as your delegate.. maybe you set the delegate wrong?

Comment: Thats wt I am confused y RouteSelectorController came in between.I done same as I posted the code on this Question.

Comment: please show us the code where you set the delegate object

Comment: I edited my question pls check it once.

Comment: None of the classes you posted here conform to the formal protocol `RouteInfoDelegate`.  `MapViewController` appears to conform to a `RouteDelegate` protocol; but I don't see any declaration of that protocol listed here.

Comment: In your first block of code, you assign the delegate of the instance of `RouteInfoController` to the `RouteSelectController` that instantiates it.  But the error is telling you that `RouteSelectController` doesn't implement the delegate method.  So Martin Ullrich's comment is correct - you're assigning the delegate wrong.

Comment: i suggest you draw a diagram (e.g. UML class diagram) to check your OO design and then go back and check your implementation

Comment: @MonishKumar hey check your self.delegate is allocated or nil means 0*0

Comment: @alanduncan: Sry its not RouteDelegate its an RouteInfoDelegate in the MapViewController deleagtes list.

Comment: @alanduncan: The flow is like when I select an Item from the list in RouteSelectController I am navigating to the  RouteInfoController from there when I again select an item from list I will go to wptInfoController.From there I will navigate back to RouteInfoController by calling the delegate method of wptInfoController.And Inside the delegate method of WptInfoController my RouteInfoDelegate method is called and its definition is in MapviewController which is not triggering... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting is pretty straightforward. It means that you're sending the message `-deleteWptFromRouteAndAppWithUID` to an instance of `RouteSelectController`, and that that class doesn't have that method. Some things to consider:

- **spelling:** If you think that you've defined that method in that class, carefully check the spelling of the method name to make sure that the method you're calling exactly matches the name of the method that you've implemented. It's a pretty long name, and it'd be easy to get wrong. Remember that capitalization counts, as does the colon (or lack of colon).
- **receiver:** Check that the object that's receiving the message really is the object that you intended. This message crops up sometimes when you've got a bad pointer, causing a case of mistaken identity.

It looks like it's the second point that's the problem in your case -- you've got an implementation of the method in MapViewController, but the error message indicates that that message is being sent to an instance of a different class (RouteSelectController). You may be changing RouteInfoController's delegate explicitly in your code somewhere, so look for that. But it may be the case that your RouteInfoController's delegate object is for some reason being deallocated, and a RouteSelectController happens to be created subsequently at that same address. When that happens, `delegate` points to the right place, but the wrong object is now there, and the error results.